# Php nl2br show /r/n

Tags: php, nl2br

When I use the function nl2br like result I see /r /n

example:

in a textarea I wrote

```
Hello,
how are you?,
fine
```

php

```
echo nl2br($_POST['message']);
```

result to screen

```
\r\nHello,
\r\nhow are you?
\r\nfin
```

how can I fix it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$newmessage = preg_replace('#(\\\r|\\\r\\\n|\\\n)#','<br />', $_POST['message']);
```

Comment: i tried all the solutions but still not working